# C++ standard default namespace

Tags: c++, namespaces

I am unsure if the two data member declarations in class B are equivalent.

```
//file0.h
namespace C
{
   typedef int Id;
}
//file1.h
namespace A
{
   typedef int Id;
}

//file2.h
namespace A
{
   class B
   {
      public:
      // ...
      //Want to add data member theId as:
      //Id theId;
      //or
      //A::Id theId;
   }
}
```

That is, in the absence of A::, is there a default namespace the C++ standard uses in cases like this one? e.g., it may default to namespace A because the class is being declared in it.

If one uses Id theId, which namespace would it use, A or C?

Edit 1: Commented out code to avoid confusion.
Edit 2: Added another "theId" with a different namespace to illustrate better the question.

Comment: [Qualified name lookup](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/qualified_lookup) vs [unqualified name lookup](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/unqualified_lookup).

Comment: Does the code even compile?

Comment: So in your case it is identical.

Comment: Is there a "default" namespace defined by the standard? No, not really. It uses the *current* namespace, which in this case is `A`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer is Id results in A::Id theId.

Why?

Id (without the A::) is an unqualified name. C++ then resorts to this rule to find the right Id:

> Member function definition For a name used inside a member function
>   body, a default argument of a member function, exception specification
>   of a member function, default member initializer, or inside a nested
>   class definition (including names of the bases from which the nested
>   class is derived), the scopes searched are the same as in class
>   definition,[...]
>
> [Class definition] the following scopes are searched:
>
> d) if this class
>   is a member of a namespace, or is nested in a class that is a member
>   of a namespace, or is a local class in a function that is a member of
>   a namespace, the scope of the namespace is searched until the
>   definition of the class, enclosing class, or function. if the lookup
>   of for a name introduced by a friend declaration: in this case only
>   the innermost enclosing namespace is considered, otherwise lookup
>   continues to enclosing namespaces until the global scope as usual.

Reference: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/unqualified_lookup